# Injecting Blazor Web Assembly into existing project with .Net Core 6

Tags: .net, visual-studio, api, asp.net-core, blazor

Please how do I inject the Blazor WebAssembly to consume the Web APIs from my already existing project on Visual studio.

Comment: See this article that describes how to host multiple projects in the same solution  - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5299017/Building-a-Blazor-WASM-and-Server-All-In-One-Solut

Comment: Thanks. What if i want to host only one project? And moreover i think the version of the ,net core is 5 cos am seeing startup file

Answer (score 0):

What you want already exits: the ASP.NET Core Hosted WASM template.

Add the ASP.NET Core Hosted WASM template to your current API project.

- Update your project's Project file:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="7.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

- Add Project dependencies to the Client and Shared projects to your project.
- Update your project's `Program`

```
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
```

- Sort out your default page/routing to what you want.

```
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
```

Look at the server project's files for guidance.

Comment: I Am sorry if am asking too much. I am just starting to wrap my head around Blazor. The thing is that is there a way for me to just inject directly my Web Api local host on swagger into Blazor app? I will appreciate if you can share me resources or videos to clarify me well on that cos i have combed through Youtube but not any one explicable enough. Thanks

Comment: @Dlaw,you could check the documents:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-6.0 ,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio add the  related services and middleware

Comment: Hello. Can you please help me on this. I watched a tutorial video where services.AddTransient<ISqlDataAccess, SqlDataAccess>();
            services.AddTransient<IContactData>, ContactData>(); was called in the startup.cs but i only have the Program.cs file. Please how do i call it in the Program.cs file.

Comment: @Dlaw - ask this as a different question with some code.  I or others will answer you.